# Implementing a dynamic Time Zone selector Angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular, timezone, momentjs, angular2-moment

I need to build a TimeZone selector in my Angular 4/5 Application. When a user changes the timezone, I expect all displayed time values on the page to update immediately.

I was planning to use:

- momentjs with timezone support using `angular2-moment` and `angular-moment-timezone`.
- To format the date use `amLocal` pipe, followed by other pipes.
- When user selects a different time zone, I am planning to call `moment.tz.setDefault(_timezone)`

With the above values from this point on gets formatted as new time zone, while currently displayed time values do not change. Angular change detection mechanism does not update displayed time values, as the input values have not changed.

I do not want to create an 'impure' pipe because of performance overheads (considering timezone change is not a frequent activity).

As fallback I can create a pipe (or use an existing one) that takes the current time zone as parameter. It actually works but I will need to pass around the current time zone value to each component and template.

I have not been able to find a way for Angular change detection to believe there is a change even when there was no change of values.

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: *I have not been able to find a way for Angular change detection to believe there is a change even when there was no change of values*: yes you have: that's called an impure pipe.

Comment: The dual binding is maybe your best option ?

Comment: When you say "does not update displayed time values", what *precisely* do you mean?  Do you just mean the values represent "now" and you want them to tick forward like on a clock?  If so, you need a timer of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

Pipes are not components (obvious), they do not have their own change detection mechanics except `pure` flag. So there two ways to achieve desired result:

1. Use smart impure pipe which will track previous value and previous formatted result. Angular's `AsyncPipe` (which is impure actually, if there was another way to do that then I believe it would be made pure) is implemented this way:

   ```
   if (value !== this.value || this.timeZoneChanged) 
   {
       this.value = value;
       this.formattedValue = ... render value ...;
   }
   return this.formattedValue;
   ```

   You can browse `AsyncPipe` source code on github.
2. Use custom component to render dates i.e. custom `ControlValueAccessor`.

Answer (score 1):

When using for example `ngx-translate` for example, switching the language imply fetching new translation. As you can see [here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/src/translate.pipe.ts) they use an impure Pipe which as you said imply performance issues.

The other way I imagine is to define a component `DateComponent` available for your whole app. That way, instead of having in your html `{{ value | formatDate }}` you'll have `<custom-date [date]="new Date()"></custom-date>`.

In your custom date component will look like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-date',
  template: '<span>{{ formatedDate }}</span>'
})
export class DateComponent {
  @Input() date: string;
  timezone: string;
  formatedDate: string;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.timezone = this.userService.getTimeZone();
    this.updateValue();
    this.userService.onTimezoneChange()
      .subscribe(timezone => {
        this.timezone = timezone;
        this.updateValue();
      });
  }

  updateValue() {
    // Do your formatting the way you want
    this.formatedDate = moment(this.date).tz(this.timezone).format();
  }
}
```